# Woocommerce custom filters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am making a custom filter for my woocommerce website. I have the posts already filtered, so as of right now I have an array of the products that I want to show.

**My question is:** Which template/function/hook would I edit to show those products efficiently?

So if someone used a woocommerce filter whilst my custom filter is in use that it will not break the page. I was considering doing it through jQuery and looping over the posts I have filtered out and inserting them into the parent container via `.html();`

Thoughts?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suspect you'll get a better answer at the Wordpress stack-exchange! Post your question there, and don't forget to actually show the filter you worry about conflicting as well!

Comment: This question is just unclear as it is and too vague. You should show the code that you are using to filter your post explaining what it does on post. Then you should tell what you really want to filter for product custom post type… There is already tons of available filters for WooCommerce products… You can search and try any of those [located in this official list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)… Nobody can guess what is in your mind by magic.